# Dependent template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

My templated function has two template parameters(`int m` and `int n`). The function returns a class `Foo<int r>`, where I want `r=m+n`.

In foo.h I have:

```
template<int m> class Foo {};
template<int m, int n>
Foo<m+n> myFunc(const Foo<m> &a, const Foo<n> &b);
```

In foo.cpp I have:

```
Foo<m+n> myFunc(const Foo<m> &a, const Foo<n> &b)
{
    return Foo<m+n>();
}
```

And finally in main.cpp:

```
#include "foo.h"
int main()
{
    myFunc(Foo<2>(), Foo<3>());
}
```

If I try this, I get a linker error.:

```
 "undefined reference to `Foo<(2)+(2)> myFunc(Foo<2> const&, Foo<2> const&)'
```

EDIT: Edited to include complete code. Maybe less clear but preferred by some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably putting the function body code in the wrong place. With (non-specialised) template functions, you generally want to put the whole function body *in the header file* and *not the source file*, otherwise the compiler cannot generate the code for that function when it is called.

Comment: Would it were otherwise and my VC might not stall while Updating Intellisense (49) .... (48) ....

Answer (score 3):

From what little you provide, the error indicates that though you've declared the function, you've not provided an implementation anywhere that the linker can see.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you haven't *defined* the function or the definition is not visible to the compiler at the point of instantiation. If you write a function body, it works:

```
template <int> class Foo {};

template<int m, int n>
Foo<m+n> myFunc(const Foo<m> &a, const Foo<n> &b) {} // NOTE: Body.

int main () {
    myFunc (Foo<1>(), Foo<2>());
}
```

---

*(sidenote: post complete code next time, please)*